# How to include generated config in cmake?

Tags: cmake

My CMakeLists.txt needs to include oem.cmake as

```
INCLUDE (oem.cmake)
```

The content of oem.cmake looks like

```
SET (PRODUCT_NAME "...")
SET (PRODUCT_VENDOR "...")
...
```

but it must be generated by a lua script

```
lua generate_oem_conf.lua "<oem>"
```

I tried ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND, but it will not be executed and reports oem.cmake is not found.

Any way to make oem.cmake to generate before including?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the command that you give to **add_custoum_command** runs when you compile your program.
**include** needs the file you want to include during configuration, i.e. when you run cmake.

You can use [execute_process](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process) for commands you want to run during configuration.
For example

```
execute_process(COMMAND "lua" "generate_oem_conf.lua \"<oem>\""
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PATH_TO_GEN_LUA_FILE} )

include(oem.cmake)
```

For this to work lua has to be in your PATH. 
Maybe you have to escape the **<** and **>** characters.